# Spaces coming from mysql_fetch_array are corrupting my links

Tags: php, mysql

```
$oku = mysql_fetch_array($yaz);
echo $oku[0];
```

this prints my `$oku[0]` value for example `hello world`

But if I use it like:

```
echo "<a href=index.php?member=" . $oku[0] . ">" . $oku[0] . "</a>";
```

it shows the hello world in text form exactly right, but link goes to index.php?member=hello

It does not contain the text after the space. How can solve this issue?

Comment: can you show the output? didnt understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the php [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.rawurlencode.php)-function to encode you string (which contains a space)

Comment: np, that's why we are here ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
printf(
    '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
    'index.php?member=' . rawurlencode($oku[0]),
    $oku[0]
);
```